# What are the release / debug sub configurations for?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

In Visual Studio Mac / Xamarin Studio there's a drop down menu inbetween the device picker and the platform picker.

This is it...

[image]

Apart from selecting release or debug, what do all the different versions do? And, in particular, why am I able to select this...

[image]

This clearly doesn't make any sense. i.e. that the configuration is specific to an iPhone simulator but it's to be deployed on to an Android simulator.

Incidentally, I'm asking this because my Android build no longer installs properly and is double it's previous size.

Comment: I'd check out this [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/demystifying-build-configurations/) it does a pretty good job of explaining the configuration manager. Also, you really only need two types of configurations `Debug` and `Release` the latter being used to replace `AppStore` and `AdHoc`.

Comment: Thanks. Well, Release-x64, Release-x82, Release-ARM and Release-AnyCPU all point to the same Android build configuration of "Release". So I'm not sure why they're there.

Comment: All of the configurations you see in your screenshot are the old configurations that use to be set up by default, and most of those can be deleted/edited now. If you created a brand new project you will see it have the newer default configuration, which it's only like 3 for `Debug`, `Debug | iPhone`, `Debug | iPhoneSimulator`, and 3 for `Release`, `Release | iPhone`, `Release | iPhoneSimulator`.

Comment: @Nick Doesn't it make sense to have two debug configs for Android? One that targets x86 and one that targets ARM?

Comment: If you right click on your Android sln and go to options > Android Build > Advanced you can change the cpu architectures you can debug to so you can have one debug config but deploy to both x86 and Arm.

Comment: Doesn’t it take longer to compile when multiple architectures are added to a build config?

Comment: I'd assume a little and I'm not exactly sure how much longer but as long as you only have those 2 architectures selected and not all of them my guess is the extra build time is negligible. Plus you don't have to worry about switching between configurations when deploying to a simulator or a device.